# how I can choose which on as element and which one is attribute

Tags: xml, database, xslt, dtd

the following is the problem for employee
I have to design the dtd, xml, xsl table for my final project

For each Employee you have the following features:

EMP_ID (1 occurrence, required)
Name (1 occurrence, required)
Salary (0 or 1 occurrence, optional)
DNO (1 occurrence, required)

According  to the above problem EMP_ID, Name, Salary, DNO can be the Employee element or attribute. regarding to occurrence which one I choose as attribute or Element can anyone tell me how to solve this problem thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Try something and come back with specific questions. Getting someone on SO to do your homework won't help you much.

Comment: Any answers to this question, as currently written, will be opinion-based. Whether or not you choose an element or an attribute will primarily be personal preference. However, sometimes there is a technical reason for choosing one over the other. For example, I'd make `EMP_ID` an attribute with the type `ID`. This will ensure that the value is unique (and allows easy referencing if needed).

Comment: For the opinions of one well respected expert, see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-eleatt/index.html But there is no right answer.

Comment: can you  Daniel Haley check on this weather it is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply Mr. Daniel Haley I have built my. dtd like this is this correct or need any changes.

```
<!ELEMENT Project (employee*,Department*)>
<!ELEMENT employee (EMPID,EName,Salary?,DNO)>
<!ELEMENT EMPID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT EName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Salary (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DNO (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST EMPID empId CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST EName empName CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Salary empSalary CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST DNO depNo CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT Department (DEP_ID,DName,Location)>
<!ELEMENT DEP_ID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Location (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST DEP_ID depId CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST DName depName CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Location dep CDATA #IMPLIED>`
```